# Make a loop AND catch using Strings instead of ints? (java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a text based rock paper scissors. I want the player to choose what they want to play to, for example "best (user response/2 + 1) out of (user response)" then it asks for verification if they would like to play to that number. If they say yes it continues the game with that score, if no it loops back up and lets them choose another number and I have an else that reminds them they can either select yes or no. When they are originally asked, letters don't effect and they are asked to try again. On the second loop around (when you say no) if you enter a String instead of an Int it crashes. Here what I have.

```
System.out.println("Best of:");
    String line = userIn.nextLine();
    while (true) {
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            try { //try catch to stop strings for a response
                bestOf = Integer.parseInt(line);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        line = userIn.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Okay, so you want to play best " + (bestOf / 2 + 1) + " of " + bestOf + "?");
    String response2 = userIn.nextLine();
    while (true) {
        if (response2.contains("n")) {
            System.out.println("What do you wish to play to then, " + name + "?");
            bestOf = userIn.nextInt();
            response2 = "y";
        } else if (response2.contains("y") || response2.contains("Y")) {
            winScore = (bestOf / 2 + 1);
            System.out.println("Okay, best " + (bestOf / 2 + 1) + " of " + bestOf + " it is!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid response! Try again.");
            response2 = userIn.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your code?Question is not clear, edit the question and add what is the expected output and what is the current output for an given input?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using parseInt use the string, in other words the input take it as string (even if is a number) them use the function "isNumber" too check if the string the user put is a number if not, do a while

```
System.out.println("Best of:");
    String line = userIn.nextLine();
    String aux = line;
    do{
          if (line.length() > 0) 
            aux = line;

        if(!isNumeric(aux)){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            line = userIn.nextLine();                
        }
    }while(!isNumeric(aux));

    bestOf = Integer.parseInt(aux);
```

so

```
     public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your loop as a method and use it in second case as well.

```
private Integer readInt(Scanner scanner){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    while (true) {
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            try { //try catch to stop strings for a response
                Integer result = Integer.parseInt(line);
                return result;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        line = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
private Integer readInt(Scanner scanner){
    Integer result;
    do{
        try{
            return scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        }
    } while (true);
}
```